# Batch for windows to excute a remote executable / command in local system

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there a way via batch that a program hosted in a remote desktop be executed locally in a local system?

Comment: Which Windows version of MS-DOS? _the last version was technically v8 in Windows Millennium Edition_. Please also take a look at [ask], and consider a total overhaul of your question.

Comment: The local and remote windows version is Windows 7

Comment: Okay, I've removed all of the references to DOS, from your question, as you're not using DOS, in any way.

Comment: FYI, MS-DOS is a dead OS that, towards the end, was used very little even in Windows 98/ME, except as a system call interface for old DOS programs that ran in a v86 mode virtual machine. Windows systems that are based on NT (everything since XP) include a batch scripting environment via the CMD shell and utility programs. This extends the COMMAND shell environment of MS-DOS; however, CMD and friends are Windows console programs, not DOS programs. This will all be dead history in a few years. Batch scripting is being phased out and replaced by PowerShell, an evidently different environment.

Comment: I have installed Powershell also - how can we achieve the objective?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to do? It seems like you want to run an executable from a file share. This is possible if it's portable or installs itself automatically. But if you have something else in mind, I think the answer is no. If we run a program that requires installed file and registry paths, it will fail to find them on our local system. Maybe this is possible with redirection in a Docker container in Windows 10. I haven't had a need to play with it yet.

Comment: We have a tool hosted on a remote box. Currently we do a remote login and then execute the command in that remote box. I am seeking a way that via some script we can connect to remote machine run the executable on local host locally - I mean as if the command is locally installed